# C# - How can I print out viewdata?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view

I was wondering how I can print out the viewdata on my view.

Here's how I pass the view data along

```
 public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            User user = db.user.Find(id);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewData["competenties"] = from usercomp in dbE.UserComp
                                       join comp in dbE.Competenties on usercomp.fk_Comp_id equals comp.comp_id
                                       where usercomp.fk_user_id == id
                                       select new { compname = comp.competentie };

            ViewData["locations"] = from userloc in dbE.UserLoc
                                    join loc in dbE.Locations on userloc.fk_location_id equals loc.loc_id
                                    where userloc.fk_user_id == id
                                    select new { locname = loc.loc_name };
            return View(user);
        }
```

for example how can I print the "*locname*" of all the location for a user on the view? I tried numerous things, but nothing seems to work so far.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to create a view model and pass that to the view, rather than doing ViewData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for example how can I print the "locname" of all the location for a
>   user on the view?

Oh, try a bit harder. Anonymous types in C# are scoped only to the current method. So as in every ASP.NET MVC application, please start by defining some view model model that will describe the data you will be using in your view:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}
```

that you will project your LINQ query to:

```
 ViewData["locations"] = 
     from userloc in dbE.UserLoc
     join loc in dbE.Locations on userloc.fk_location_id equals loc.loc_id
     where userloc.fk_user_id == id
     select new MyViewModel { LocationName = loc.loc_name };
```

OK, and now that you know what you have projected against, you could work with this type in your view:

```
@foreach (var model in (IEnumerable<MyViewModel>)ViewData["locations"])
{
    <div>@model.LocationName</div>
}
```

---

The code I have shown so far is of course only the first step improvement that could be done in your situation. It's just for starters. Obviously writing such code should never be done because this is a crime against the humanity. The proper way to do this is to have a real view model to project against:

```
public class Location
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Competence
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Competence> Competences { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your controller action project against this model:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    User user = db.user.Find(id);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var competences = 
        from usercomp in dbE.UserComp
        join comp in dbE.Competenties on usercomp.fk_Comp_id equals comp.comp_id
        where usercomp.fk_user_id == id
        select new Competence { Name = comp.competentie };

    var locations = 
        from userloc in dbE.UserLoc
        join loc in dbE.Locations on userloc.fk_location_id equals loc.loc_id
        where userloc.fk_user_id == id
        select new Location { Name = loc.loc_name };

    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        User = user,
        Locations = locations.ToList(), // eagerly fetch the data that will be needed in the view
        Competences = competences.ToList(), // eagerly fetch the data that will be needed in the view
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

and more than obviously the final step is to have your view strongly typed to the view model we just defined:

```
@model MyViewModel
```

OK, now it's more than trivially easy to access whatever information you need

```
@foreach (var location in Model.Locations)
{
    <div>@location.Name</div>
}
```

or another:

```
@foreach (var competence in Model.Competences)
{
    <div>@competence.Name</div>
}
```

or if you wanted to greet your user or something:

```
<div>
    Hello @Model.User.FirstName and welcome back to my super duper website
</div>
```

You will even find that Visual Studio has some pretty decent IntelliSense when you are working with strongly typed view models in your ASP.NET MVC views, so that you should not be relying on some dynamic casts and stuff that is like a tick-tacking bomb mechanism waiting to explode in your face (or your users faces) at runtime.

So the conclusion from this post is that you should never use `ViewData` or `ViewBag` in an ASP.NET MVC application. Those 2 things are like cancer that should be eradicated. Search for those keywords in your ASP.NET MVC solution (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F</kbd>) and if there are occurrences, operate them.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it was very helpfull

Comment: Hi, I followed you're advice, and I'm starting to understadn the structure, hoawever I have the error "The entity or complex type 'P104.Models.Locations' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query", any advice? I pretty much followed your code.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you do not want to use a ViewModel, you can do something like this:

At the beginning of your View you declare some objects;

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    var myObject = ViewData["locations"];
    var properties = myObject.GetType().GetProperties();
}
```

And to show the data of the propertie you do this:

```
<label>@myObject.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "locname").GetValue(myObject)</label>
```